# SVG not generating correct base64 image

Tags: svg, base64

I want to convert svg to base64 image. The btoa(xml) is not generating the correct image.

Please find the code here [jsFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/h2L3gw88/397/)

```
var svg = document.querySelector('svg');
var img = document.querySelector('img');
var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');

// get svg data
var xml = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(svg);

// make it base64
var svg64 = btoa(xml);
var b64Start = 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,';
```

Can anyone help me with this? 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To expand a little on [LeBeau's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49453798/1869660):

- Instead of CSS styles, use `width/height` and `viewBox` on the SVG element to fit everything into the image.
  `<svg ... width="700" height="160" viewBox="-40,-120, 700,160">`
- Wait until `img` is loaded before you draw in onto the canvas, or else nothing gets drawn.
  `img.onload = e => canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(img, 0, 0);`

https://jsfiddle.net/h2L3gw88/437/

Answer (score 1):

It is encoding fine.  It is the `style` attribute in your SVG that is causing your problems.  Remove it and things get better.

Also, your fiddle was doing unnecessary encoding of the XML before base64 encoding.  You don't need that.

```
var svg64 = btoa(xml);
```

is fine.

See: https://jsfiddle.net/h2L3gw88/425/